# Decoding sentences in Java using arrays

Tags: java

So I am doing some practice problems for an upcoming exam and one of the problems is posing a bit of a challenge to me.

The problem states that our code should take a string that has been encoded and decode it.  It must work as follows:

Each letter is decoded using the letter immediately before it in the alphabet ("b" becomes "a", "c" becomes "b" ect.)
"a" becomes "z".
each digit works the same way, 8 becomes 7, 5 becomes 4.
0 becomes 9.
characters neither letters nor digits are unchanged.

THE ONLY JAVA METHOD I CAN USE IS IO

Ex:

```
NFFU NF BU 23 JO UIF CFMM UPXFS
meet me at 12 in the bell tower
```

heres my current code, i cannot decide whether to use for loops or not.  TBH I am not really sure how to tackle this.

```
public class prb1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char letter[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        int num[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        System.out.println("Enter Message");
        String mssg=IO.readString();

        for(char i=0; i<letter.length; i++){
            System.out.print(letter[i]--);}

        for(int j=0; j<num.length; j++){
            System.out.print(num[j]--);             
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? If you are asking if you need to use a loop, then the answer is YES

Answer (score 0):

The basic is like this. But this doesn't account yet for the a => z conversion.

```
    String cypher ="ABCDEF";
    String plain = "";
    for (char c : cypher.toCharArray())
        plain += (char) (c - 1);
    System.out.println(plain);
```

With the modulo A => Z, it looks like this:

```
int A = 'A';
plain += (char) (((c - A - 1 + 26) % 26) + A);
```

The `+26` is needed because java says `-1 % 26 == -1` instead of 25.

So this just works for A-Z, but you can easily modify it to work for wider ranges.

Comment: Thank you, however I forgot to mention I cannot use java methods cyphere.to.  the only methods i can use are IO mods.

Comment: I don't understand that requirement. What is cyphere.to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate through each character of the message and subtract one from its ascii code if its not a space, an `a`, or an `A`:

```
String message = "NFFU NF BU 23 JO UIF CFMM UPXFS";
String result = "";
for (char thisChar : message.toCharArray()) {
    if (thisChar == ' ') {
        result += " ";
    } else if(thisChar == 'a') {
        result += 'z';
    } else if (thisChar == 'A') {
        result += 'Z';
    } else
        result += (char)(thisChar - 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
String message = "NFFU NF BU 23 JO UIF CFMM UPXFS";
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i ++) {
    char thisChar = message.charAt(i);
    if (thisChar == ' ') {
        result += " ";
    } else if(thisChar == 'a') {
        result += 'z';
    } else if (thisChar == 'A') {
        result += 'Z';
    } else
        result += (char)(thisChar - 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Technically,

```
    else if(thisChar == 'a') {
        result += 'z';
    } else if (thisChar == 'A') {
        result += 'Z';
    }
```

could be shortened to:

```
    else if(thisChar == 'a' || thisChar == 'A') {
        result += (char)(thisChar + 25);
    }
```

Comment: Ok thank you.  Now how would I configure this for 'a' 'a'.  because it sets a = ` instead of z.